# Question about about Stokes Theorem

Tags: calculus

Hello I'm trying to do this exercise but i dont know how to do it.. if $z$ was $0$ it would be simple, but $z$ is between $-1$ and $1$.

> **Q**: If $S=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=2; -1\leq z\leq 1\}$ and $F(x,y,z) = (-x-y+xz^2 , x+z , z+e^{x+y})$. Use Stokes theorem to calculate $\int\int_S \text{curl}F\cdot dS$

Comment: On the original image it says $1\le z\le 1$.

Comment: It's beetween -1 and 1. Sorry, I did it on LaTeX. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the $e^{x+y}$ is correct? Unless I'm missing something, this leads to some rather messy integration, which doesn't have a elementary solution (specifically, it involves modified Bessel Functions).

Comment: Yes, this question is from last year exam, but my professor doesn't give us the solutions. Btw, we did not learn Bessel Functions.

Comment: Maybe we have to choose an orientation for S and choose either z=-1 or z=1 ?? Thats the only way?

Comment: @Tom The $z$-coordinate of the field does not matter since $z=$const on the boundary, so $dz=0$ in the line integral.

Comment: I do not see any trouble with the exercise. Apply [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem) to get the line integral over the boundary of $S$ which consists of two circles of opposite orientations. The integral can be easily calculated by definition using the canonical parametrization of circles by $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: If I was asked to choose the orientation, can i choose to do the exercise with z=1 , therefore x^2+y^2=1 , and solve it??

Comment: @MathScientist You have two parts of the boundary: $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=1$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=-1$. Orientation is by default from exterior surface normal, so by the right hand rule the circle with $z=1$ goes clockwise and the circle with $z=-1$ counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stokes theorem we may convert the surface integral to the line integral as
$$
\iint_S\operatorname{curl}F\cdot dS=\int_{\partial S}F\cdot dr.
$$
The boundary $\partial S$ consists of two circles $\gamma_+$ and $\gamma_-$ corresponding to the intersections of the sphere with two planes $z=\pm 1$. Assuming the outward-pointing normal for $S$ the parameterization for those looks like
$$
\gamma_+\colon\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x&=&\cos t,\\
y&=&\sin t,\\
z&=&1,
\end{array}
\right.\qquad t\colon 2\pi\to 0,\qquad
\gamma_-\colon\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x&=&\cos t,\\
y&=&\sin t,\\
z&=&-1,
\end{array}
\right.\qquad t\colon 0\to2\pi
$$
Substitution to the line integral together with its definition yields
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial S}&=\int_{\gamma_+}+\int_{\gamma_-}=\\
&=\int_{2\pi}^0[(-\sin t)(-\sin t)+(\cos t+1)\cos t]\,dt+
\int_0^{2\pi}[(-\sin t)(-\sin t)+(\cos t-1)\cos t]\,dt=\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}(-2\cos t)\,dt=0.
\end{align}